# Clicking a button should calculate a value and return the query but doesn't

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

I'm writing an ASP webapp, and there's an update button at the bottom.  When the update button is clicked, it is supposed to get the data from two cells in a table (one is a checkbox and the other is a text input (the value will be a double).  I wrote a javascript function to get the value of the checkbox and put it in the rest of the updated URL string.  Here it is:

```
<script>
function getUpdateHTML()
{

var updatestring = "window.location='RollInventoryViewDev.asp?YNChecked=";
updatestring = updatestring + document.getElementById("cellRollLockoutYN").checked + "&";

updatestring = updatestring + "action=update&sort=roll_id&sortdir=<%=intSortDir%>&id=<%=intRollID%>&iddt=<%=StrRollIdDt%>&seqnum=<%=intRollSeqNum%>&findesc=<%=strRollFinishDescription%>&fincd=<%=strRollFinishCD%>&diam=<%=dblRollDiameter%>&crown=<%=dblRollCrown%>&crownaim=<%=dblRollCrownAim%>&prosrough=<%=intRollProsRoughness%>&peaksrough=<%=intRollPeaksRoughness%>&hardness=<%=intRollHardness%>&metalcd=<%=strRollMetalCD%>&rolltype=<%=strRollType%>&lockout=<%=chrRollLockoutYN%>&depthavg=<%=dblProductPatternDepthAvg%>'";
return updatestring;
}
</script>
```

Here is where it gets called:

```
<input type=button value="Update" onClick="getUpdateHTML()"></input>
```

After the function executes, I want the string to execute.  So, for example, the function might return:

```
RollInventoryViewDev.asp?YNChecked=true&action=update&sort=roll_id&sortdir=0&id=9307&iddt=1/1/1995&seqnum=89&findesc=VIT&fincd=VIT &diam=24.651&crown=0.0041&crownaim=&prosrough=225&peaksrough=150&hardness=832&metalcd=2FST&rolltype=Work&lockout=Y&depthavg=1.5
```

I want the page to reload with that URL, but I'm not sure how to make that happen.

Sorry for the stupid question.  This is literally my first time using Javascript.  I was hoping to just be able to do all of this using ASP but I decided that it would be easier to implement in Javascript.

Comment: `window.open("newurl.asp?...","_self")` ?

Comment: Perfect.  Want to submit that as an answer?

Comment: Nice that i could help, submitted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To open a new adress using javascript use this `window.open("newurl.asp?...","_self")`

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui, did you see my comment under the question?

Answer (score 0):

If you're returning the string referencing the function window.location:

```
<script>
function getUpdateHTML()
{
    var updatestring = "window.location='RollInventoryViewDev.asp?YNChecked=true&action=update&sort=roll_id&sortdir=0&id=9307&iddt=1/1/1995&seqnum=89&findesc=VIT&fincd=VIT &diam=24.651&crown=0.0041&crownaim=&prosrough=225&peaksrough=150&hardness=832&metalcd=2FST&rolltype=Work&lockout=Y&depthavg=1.5'";

    return updatestring;
}
</script>
```

then you can execute its javascript using eval:

```
<input type=button value="Update" onClick="eval(getUpdateHTML());"></input>
```